# I got an scroll position problems when I link anchor from page1 to page2 with a fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, anchor

I got an scroll position problem. When I link anchor from page2 to page3, page3 is under the fixed header. BTW, page1 and page2 share the same fixed header and in the same `<iframe></iframe>`. Here are my page:

page1:

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <header class="fixed"></header>
        <iframe src="page2"></iframe>
    </body>   
</html>
```

page2:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="navigation>
            <a href="page3.html></a>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            content
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

page3:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="navigation>
            <a href="page2.html class="anchor"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            content
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

When I click the link a.anchor in the page2, the whole iframe is under the header. But I can make it look normal when I move my mouse to the top. 
Here's the example of the [page3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZITG.png). When I link page2 to page3, the scroll doesn't go to the top of the whole html. The distance between then is the height of the fixed header.

---

I try to change the scroll position of the window by Javascript, but it dosen't work. How to solve it?

I hope that I make my question clear to you.

Comment: The link is in the ??? && The header is not change(which header???) &&  but the content is under the header???

Comment: I just modified my question. Sorry for that.

Comment: You want the page which contains the iframe change header after user click the link in iframe?

Comment: No,sorry that I make you confused. The header is fixed. I just want the part content of the iframe to be changed. And I want that everytime I click the link, the scroll is in the top of the page.

Comment: @DavidGuan Thank you for being so patient.My English is not that good. This is my first time to ask question on the stackoverflow.  So I may not make the question clear. I modified the question again. I hope you can understand this time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have placed your anchors, so if you want to change you HTML page and directly go to an anchor, your link should look like :

```
 <a href="usermgm.html#anchor">
```

More informations on the [W3C website](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)